# Why is 'colliderect' not detecting collision?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I am trying to make collision detection between the walls of a room and my character, Michael Scarn. However, nothing is being detected. I know this because I told the program to print "Collide" when there is a collision, but nothing is being detected. Is it a small mistake or a bigger mistake in my code? Can anyone fix this?

```
class Scarn(object):  # creates attributes for Michael Scarn (player)

def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.vel = 8
    self.walkCount = 0
    self.standing = False
    self.left = False
    self.right = False
    self.up = False
    self.down = False
    self.sleeping = True
    self.scarn_hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y + 11, 32, 64)

def draw(self, win):  # draws Michael Scarn and his movements

    if self.walkCount + 1 >= 3:
        self.walkCount = 0

    if self.sleeping:
        win.blit(scarn_sleeping, (340, 150))
    if not self.sleeping:
        if self.left:
            win.blit(scarn_left[self.walkCount // 1], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(scarn_right[self.walkCount // 1], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.up:
            win.blit(scarn_up[self.walkCount // 1], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.down:
            win.blit(scarn_down[self.walkCount // 1], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
    else:
        if self.left:
            win.blit(scarn_left[0], (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(scarn_right[0], (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.up:
            win.blit(scarn_up[0], (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.down:
            win.blit(scarn_down[0], (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.standing:
            win.blit(scarn_forward_standing[0], (self.x, self.y))

pygame.display.update()
```

def apartment_movement():  # movement in the apartment / collision detection

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

collision = False
for wall in apartment_walls:
    collision = scarn.scarn_hitbox.colliderect(wall)
    if collision:
        break

if collision:
    scarn.left = False
    scarn.right = False
    scarn.up = False
    scarn.down = False
    scarn.standing = False
    scarn.sleeping = False
    print("Collide")
if not collision:
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and scarn.x > 110 - scarn.width - scarn.vel:  # allows the player to move left
        scarn.x -= scarn.vel
        scarn.left = True
        scarn.right = False
        scarn.up = False
        scarn.down = False
        scarn.standing = False
        scarn.sleeping = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and scarn.x < 795 - scarn.width - scarn.vel:  # allows the player to move right
        scarn.x += scarn.vel
        scarn.right = True
        scarn.left = False
        scarn.up = False
        scarn.down = False
        scarn.standing = False
        scarn.sleeping = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and scarn.y > 130 - scarn.height - scarn.vel:
        scarn.y -= scarn.vel
        scarn.up = True
        scarn.right = False
        scarn.left = False
        scarn.down = False
        scarn.standing = False
        scarn.sleeping = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and scarn.y < 540 - scarn.height - scarn.vel:
        scarn.y += scarn.vel
        scarn.down = True
        scarn.right = False
        scarn.left = False
        scarn.up = False
        scarn.standing = False
        scarn.sleeping = False
    else:  # clarifies the player is not moving left or right
        scarn.walkCount = 0


# apartment walls
apartment_walls = [pygame.Rect(243, 60, 8, 275),
pygame.Rect(510, 60, 8, 275),
pygame.Rect(243, 421, 215, 5),
pygame.Rect(243, 330, 220, 5),
pygame.Rect(510, 421, 145, 5),
pygame.Rect(510, 330, 145, 5),
pygame.Rect(700, 421, 57, 5),
pygame.Rect(700, 330, 57, 5),
pygame.Rect(43, 410, 120, 10),
pygame.Rect(510, 335, 5, 90),
pygame.Rect(460, 335, 5, 90),
pygame.Rect(700, 335, 5, 90),
pygame.Rect(650, 335, 5, 90)]
```

Comment: You're passing an array of rects rather than a single rect.

Comment: Is there a way for me to keep the list and still fix the error?

Comment: You'll need to loop through it and call ```colliderect()``` on each one individually.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you fix your code formatting and make a [mre]? This will help others to run and test your code and understand your question better.

Comment: I don't think I can make the code smaller. Sorry it's a little bit big

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `colliderect` on each wall individually. Remember to stop checking and break out of the loop once there's a collision.

```py
collision = False

for wall in apartment_walls:
    collision = scarn.scarn_hitbox.colliderect(wall)
    if collision == True: break

if collision:
    scarn.left = False
    scarn.right = False
    scarn.up = False
    scarn.down = False
    scarn.standing = False
    scarn.sleeping = False

if not collision:
    # etc
```

Comment: Now my character is just moving around the screen really fast when I move it

Comment: See my edit. Scarn was being moved for every non-collision

Comment: Now there isn't an error, but the collisions aren't working

Comment: Scarn is just walking normally without boundaries

Comment: @Blazian444 when a collision is detected, you need to move back the player. It's plenty of similar questions on stackoverflow, try to search for them.

Comment: What does moving back the player mean?

Comment: Alright, so it turns out that a collision isn't even being detected. I told the program to print "Collide" if there was a collision, but nothing was printed.

Comment: Make sure that Scarn's hitbox is also moved when Scarn is moved.